# Build columns while running a query in yii2

Tags: yii2

Create columns while running query in yii2

in controller : 
query :

```
$query=Reports::find()->select(['report As type','title','imageFile','id','body'])->where(['like', 'title',''.$test.'' ])->orderby('id desc');
```

i would build column type but Does not work.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you've got.

Comment: Bizley  . in  ['report As type',...    column type build . similar : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union3

Comment: Have you got `type` property in `Reports` model?

Comment: No I do not have

Comment: 'report As type'   .. constant report  .... ' "report" as type '  but not work.
' 'report' as type' but not work .. syntax error

Comment: @scaisEdge already answered, I bet he can help you with your problem.

Comment: $myModels->type .. Where to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for  see  the result of alias  you should add  in your Reports model a public var with the same name  for get the value

```
  class Reports extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {

        public $type;

        .....
```

then you can access to the value as

```
    $myModels->type
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
            CUSTOMER_ID, 
            "tblOne" AS Source
        FROM tblOne
    UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CUSTOMER_ID,
            "tblTwo" AS Source
        FROM tblTwo  
-----------------
in yii2 not work .. syntax error